# How To Create Multiple Arrays From a Single Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I getting form data in my console like this:

```
{item[0][sku]: 'EC1000-WMK', item[0][qty]: '1', item[1][sku]: 'POP-11', item[1][qty]: '1', form_key: 'ZuQxqBMHmidjUxEt'}
form_key: "ZuQxqBMHmidjUxEt"
item[0][qty]: "1"
item[0][sku]: "EC1000-WMK"
item[1][qty]: "1"
item[1][sku]: "POP-11"
```

This is how the above data created:

```
        $.fn.getFormData = function(){
            var data = {};
            var dataArray = $(this).serializeArray();
            console.log(data);

            console.log(dataArray);
            for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
                console.log(dataArray);
                data[dataArray[i].name] = dataArray[i].value;
            }
            return data;
        }
```

but I want to make it like:

```
[
    { "sku": "EC1000-WMK", "qty": "1" }
    { "sku": "POP-11", "qty": "1" }
]
```

Comment: Except that your `I want to make it like:` data in not valid JSON I assume you mean `[
{ "sku": "EC1000-WMK", "qty": "1" }, { "sku": "POP-11", "qty": "1" }
]`

Comment: yeah you're right.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, your desired and current data are exactly the same, just being presented differently. Try JSON.stringify to make the data look like the bottom output.

Comment: Yes, but I tried myJSON.stringify and it doesn't help.

Comment: Given data matching your first line (console.log(data)), JSON.stringify gives you *exactly* the output you've requested: https://jsfiddle.net/6pqv8dLk/

Comment: Instead of copying and posting *some malformatted* Data, I hope it's not hard to right click the data from the browser Console, **Copy** it, and paste the well formatted one instead. No?

Comment: Sorry but I'm getting dynamic data and I need to create an array for each product and send to send it to ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Use Input fields name be like

```
<input name="item.0.sku" />
<input name="item.0.qty" />
<input name="item.1.sku" />
<input name="item.2.qty" />
```

& then use this function
Here is the function which converts all form inputs to JSON format

```
const jsonSerialize = ($this) => {
    $this = $this.find('input, select');
    let data = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < $this.length; i++) {
        let el = $this[i];
        let val = el.value;
        if (!val) val = "";
        let fullName = el.getAttribute("name");
        if (!fullName) continue;
        let fullNameParts = fullName.split('.');
        let prefix = '';
        let stack = data;
        for (let k = 0; k < fullNameParts.length - 1; k++) {
            prefix = fullNameParts[k];
            if (!stack[prefix]) {
                stack[prefix] = {};
            }
            stack = stack[prefix];
        }
        prefix = fullNameParts[fullNameParts.length - 1];
        if (stack[prefix]) {
            let newVal = stack[prefix] + ',' + val;
            stack[prefix] += newVal;
        } else {
            stack[prefix] = val;
        }
    }
    return data
}

let $form = $('form');
params = jsonSerialize($form)
```

Hope may this work for you